# How to encode image from C++ and decode image from Python through Redis?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, redis

The project I am doing requires efficeintly(<50ms) communicate image(5MP RGB) between two process. One process is running C++, one process is running Python.
The problem is I cannot get origin image back when I did the encoding & decoding.

On C++ side I am encode the image then convert to Base64 and send HTTP request to  Python server.

```
#include<opencv2/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include<hiredis/hiredis.h>
#include<httplib.h>
#include "cpp-base64/base64.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace cv;

std::string Mat2Base64(const Mat &image, std::string imgType){
    std::vector<uchar> buf;
    imencode(imgType, image, buf);
    std::string img_data = base64_encode(buf.data(), buf.size(),false);
    return img_data;
}

int main(){
    httplib::Client cli("localhost:5000");
    redisContext *context = redisConnect("localhost",6379);

    std::string image_path = "20230315184958935.jpg";
    Mat image = imread(image_path);
    std::string b64_image = Mat2Base64(image,".bmp");
    redisCommand(context,"SET mykey1 %s",b64_image.c_str());
    auto res = cli.Post("/1","{\"redis_image_key\":\"mykey1\"}","application/json");
    std::cout<<res->status<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On python side I did the conversion like this:

```
def redisReadImage(db,load_key=mykey1):
    image_s = db.get(load_key) #get string image from RedisDB
    image_b = np.array(bytearray(base64.b64decode(image_s)),np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode(image_b,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return image
```

However the image is corrupted. I am not quite confident with the base64 encoding, what did I miss  to make it all wrong.

Comment: Why are you bothering with base64 encoding? Redis values can be arbitrary binary strings. See the %b specifier in the [hiredis documentation](https://github.com/redis/hiredis#sending-commands)

Comment: @Botje I am assuming base64 is the most common way to encode image and I googled it find a lot of them. So I "borrowed" part of the code? Not quite sure about this. Or should I try raw data flattened?

Comment: @Botje Oh right, this "%b". Thanks

Comment: base64 is a way to encode arbitrary binary data if your transport medium might damage non-ASCII data. Since Redis supports binary data, you can skip that part. The next layer down is your decision to decode the JPEG to a bitmap and then re-encode to the BMP format. Why not send the JPEG directly?

Comment: @Botje Yes I can do that. I want to restore the origin image for now. In real situation I will get a image from C++ memory, that is the lossless image.

Comment: Then just ship the in-memory image as a BMP  and read it as such in your Python code.

Comment: @Botje You are suggesting Memory Sharing between c++ and python? I feel a little bit uncomfortable to do this, Which might incur memory unsafety?

Comment: No, I am suggesting you encode your images in the BMP format and send that as binary data over Redis.

Comment: Here's a project I did that looks at storing image data in Redis - the comments above are correct... you can store the images directly in Redis as binary.  I have Python example code for putting them in and out of Redis this way and supporting video content.  Note that later I moved the project to store images in JSON docs then you need base64 due to JSON standards. https://simonprickett.dev/taking-pictures-with-raspberry-pi-and-redis/